# Dapper INSERT AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, exception, dapper, blazor

I'm currently trying out Dapper and am really surprised how easy it can be to make "All-Day" statements in just a short amount of time.
I'm working on a Blazor WebAssembly project and am trying to make simple SELECT and INSERT statements.
I'll try to lay out everything as clear as possible to speed up the answering-process.
I have 2 projects, one a simple .Net Standard 2.0 class library with 4 classes which are used for the background-work like SQL and the BlazorWebAssembly. Now an overview over the classes in the ClassLibrary:

ProjektData.cs (the Blazor App calls the methods):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BlazorBoardcardsAppData
{
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using BlazorBoardcardsAppData.Models;

    public class ProjektData
    {
        private readonly AccessDataAccess db;

        public ProjektData(AccessDataAccess db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }

        public Task<List<ProjektModel>> GetProjekte()
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Projekte";

            return this.db.LoadData<ProjektModel, dynamic>(sql, new { });
        }

        public void SaveProjekte<I>()
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO Projekte (sName, sBeschreibung) " +
                         "VALUES (@sName, @sBeschreibung);";

            this.db.SaveData(sql, new { });
        }
    }
}
```

and AccessDataAccess.cs (where I already played around with different approaches to fix this problem)

```
namespace BlazorBoardcardsAppData
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Data.OleDb;
    using System.Linq;

    using BlazorBoardcardsAppData.Models;

    using Dapper;

    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;


    public class AccessDataAccess
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration config;

        public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = "Default";

        public AccessDataAccess(IConfiguration config)
        {
            this.config = config;
        }

        public async Task<List<T>> LoadData<T, U>(string sql, U parameters)
        {
            string connectionString = this.config.GetConnectionString(ConnectionString);
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                var data = await con.QueryAsync<T>(sql, parameters);
                return data.ToList();
            }
        }

        public void SaveData<U>(string sql, U parameters)
        {
            string connectionString = this.config.GetConnectionString(ConnectionString);
            //ProjektModel t = new ProjektModel
            //{
            //    sName = "test",
            //    sBeschreibung = "test",
            //    bAbgeschlossen = false,
            //    bDokuVorhanden = true,
            //    dAusstehendFte = 1,
            //    dGesamtFte = 2,
            //    lKanbanProjekt = 2314,
            //    sAbrechnungsmethode = "test",
            //    sErforderlicheLizenzen = "test",
            //    sExterneKontakte = "test",
            //    sGeplanteErweiterung = "test",
            //    sRaciqA = "test",
            //    sRaciqC = "test",
            //    sRaciqQ = "test",
            //    sRaciqR = "test",
            //    sRaciqI = "test",
            //    sZielgruppe = "test"
            //};
            //List<ProjektModel> u = new List<ProjektModel>();
            //u.Add(t);
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con.Execute(sql, new {
                    sName = "test",
                    sBeschreibung = "test",
                    bAbgeschlossen = false,
                    bDokuVorhanden = true,
                    dAusstehendFte = 1,
                    dGesamtFte = 2,
                    lKanbanProjekt = 2314,
                    sAbrechnungsmethode = "test",
                    sErforderlicheLizenzen = "test",
                    sExterneKontakte = "test",
                    sGeplanteErweiterung = "test",
                    sRaciqA = "test",
                    sRaciqC = "test",
                    sRaciqQ = "test",
                    sRaciqR = "test",
                    sRaciqI = "test",
                    sZielgruppe = "test"
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is to INSERT into the SQL-Database using the "ProjektModel" as a model for the parameters.
I tried several approaches, the commented code being one of them.
The SELECT statement works like a charm so I can exclude a connection problem or something like that.
I tried the ExecuteAsync but no difference, the exception always appears at the same position:

@EDIT: This screenshot is from the SQLMapper partial class from Dapper

[image: In the SQLMapper partial class from Dapper]

And just for completion the call from the other project (Blazor project which uses the DLL with the Dapper methods)

```
@page "/"
@page "/boardcards"

@using BlazorBoardcardsAppData
@using BlazorBoardcardsAppData.Models

@inject ProjektData PjData
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime
@inject ProjektModel TProjektModel
@inject ProjektDataDictionary ProjektDataDictionary

<header>
    <link href="css/BoardcardsSite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</header>
<body>
    <h1>Projekt Boardkarten</h1>

    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <button @onclick="@AddProjektToTable">Add</button>
        <p id="TextPaddingSpacer" class="col mb-0">Alle Stundenzettel der ** Komponenten</p>
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-2" type="search" placeholder="Suchen" aria-label="Suchen"
               @bind-value="SearchTerms" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
    </div>

    @if (filteredProjects == null)
    {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    }
    else
    {
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="BoardcardsNameColumnWidth">Name</th>
                    <th>Beschreibung</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var projects in filteredProjects)
                {
                    <tr class="TableRows" @onclick="@(e => OpenNewTab(projects))">
                        <td>@projects.sName</td>
                        @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(projects.sBeschreibung) || projects.sBeschreibung.Equals("?"))
                        {
                            <td>(Keine Informationen)</td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td>@projects.sBeschreibung</td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
</body>

@code {
    private List<ProjektModel> projects;

    private string SearchTerms { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        projects = await PjData.GetProjekte();
        if (ProjektDataDictionary.AllProjekt.Count == 0)
        {
            foreach (ProjektModel projektModel in projects)
            {
                ProjektDataDictionary.AllProjekt[projektModel.gID] = projektModel;
            }
        }
    }

    private List<ProjektModel> filteredProjects => projects.Where(x => x.sName.ToLower().Contains(SearchTerms.ToLower())
                                                                    || (x.sBeschreibung?.ToLower().Contains(SearchTerms.ToLower()) ?? false)).ToList();
    private async Task OpenNewTab(ProjektModel pj)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Open", $"/BoardcardViewer/{pj.gID}");
    }

    private void AddProjektToTable()
    {
        PjData.SaveProjekte<ProjektModel>();
    }
}
```

Where AddProjectToTable is the call.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is the third question I've seen in as many days regarding `AccessViolationException` and *seemingly* valid usage. I wonder if there's a recent update to System.Data.SqlClient/MS.Data.SqlClient that broke something

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Here is the ConnectionString just in Case: Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=HANKE\\HANKE;Database=Boardcards;Trusted_Connection=Yes;

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should create command in opened connection. Now, you create command and then open connection (if it is closed). Try to change this (first open connection, and then create a command).

The next thing that you should be aware of is:

```
await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(command.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Try to remove ConfigureAwait and see what happens. If it works, try then to change it to:

```
await (cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(command.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false));
```

Comment: This is the code from the extension Dapper. I didnt write that code.
My bad edited it